# (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() convert to string but not change format

Tags: powershell

When you use the (Get-Date) cmdlet you get, for example, a nice format like in the code below. But if you use the ToString() you get it in a format, for example, 6/22/2019 2:25:34 PM

How do I convert it to a string but maintain the original formatting?

```
(Get-Date).ToString()
6/22/2019 2:25:34 PM

vs....


Get-Date
Saturday, June 22, 2019 2:25:04 PM
```

Comment: you seem to have a _very common_ misunderstanding of what you are seeing when you use `Get-Date` on its own. [*grin*] you are seeing the _powershell display system formatting for that data type_. that has very little to do with the actual _data_. the `.ToString()` formatter uses a different format instruction from the display system formatter. so, if you want to get a specific format, do as `AdminOfThings` or `DanielCheng` mention and give the `ToString()` method the specific format that you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Universal Full format specifier (`U`) with the `ToString()` method, you can return the Universal Time as a string.

```
(Get-Date).ToString('U')
```

**Testing Date to String Conversion and Output Type:**

```
(Get-Date).ToString('U')
Saturday, June 22, 2019 3:11:51 PM
(Get-Date).ToString('U').GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

This alternative may not be the most elegant way, but it gets the job done.

```
((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() | Out-String).Trim()
```

See [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8) for more information on how the format specifiers work.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a DateTimeFormatInfo into the ToString method.

```
[System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::new().FullDateTimePattern
```

which gives:

```
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

end:

```
(Get-Date).ToString([System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::new().FullDateTimePattern)
```

results in:

```
Saturday, 22 June 2019 11:15:37
```